# rewriting a column in R

Tags: r, function

in my dataset I got a column containing conflict intensity with a rating (1, 2) - now I would like to change this to a Y/N dummie (so instead of intensity rating I want to know if there was a conflict or not in given country in given year) - meaning if there is a NA it should become a 0 if there is any number it should become a 1. The pictures should display it easier :)

I am working with R since 3 days :D so I am very new - I figured out to replicate and rename the column - no I just need to rewrite the content of it, I think the if(){} code might be helpful here - but I dont know what needs to come first in the coding of the function - so I d appreciate help a lot !! thanks :)

this is the original column

[image]

and this is the column replicated & renamed - where only the rewriting of the numbers is missing - the red ones are the desired outcome :)

[image]

Comment: (1) Don't post data/code as images (for many reasons, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/)), just post the data itself (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info). (2) Welcome to R! This is just `dat$conflict_YN <- +!is.na(dat$conflict_YN)`.

Comment: Please use `dput()` to output your object so we can tell what type it is and more easily use your values

Comment: thanks for the information! makes sense - sry!  figured it out - thanks a lot to all :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case `df` is your dataframe.

```r
df$conflict_YN <- ifelse(is.na(df$conflict_intensity), 0, 1)
```

Example:

```r
conflict_intensity <- c(1,2,NA)
df <- as.data.frame(conflict_intensity)
df$conflict_YN <- ifelse(is.na(df$conflict_intensity), 0, 1)
```

Output:

```r
> df
  conflict_intensity conflict_YN
1                  1           1
2                  2           1
3                 NA           0
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to make a new column with something like this

```
!is.na(dataframe$conflict_YN)
```

The ! means "not" or "opposite"

is.na() returns a 1 for a value that is NA and a 1 for everything else. So !is.na() will return a  0 for NA and a 1 for everything else.

dataframe is the name I made up for your dataframe or data table.

Have fun with R.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply guys!!! Figured it out - thanks :)